# Decreasing the computational speed of Gaussian elimination of a complex linear system in a special case.

Tags: matrices, fourier-analysis

The solution of the complex linear system $Ax = b$ of $n$ equations can be computed using
Gaussian elimination with $O(n^3)$ complex multiplications. 
However, how can we show that if $E=exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n})$ and $A$ has the elements $A_{kj} = E^{kj}$, the solution can be obtained in at most $O(n^2)$ operations?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the matrix $A$ in advance and it is regular, you can calculate its inverse $A^{-1}$ and just multiply the vector $b$ by it, avoiding any need for Gaussian elimination. Clearly, this requires $n^2$ complex multiplications (and $n(n-1)$ additions).

If the indices $j$ and $k$ in your definition of matrix $A$ run from $0$ to $(n-1)$, the resulting matrix is a non-normalized version of certain [well-known one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix) and its inverse is the same, except for a multiplicative factor of $n$ (i.e. $AA=nI$ or, equivalently, $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{n}A$). If they run from $1$ to $n$, you'll need to fiddle with re-ordering the rows a little.